# Sum up the differences between every element of a vector and a given threshold

Tags: r, loops, vector, difference

I have the following vector:

```
my_vec <- c(2,3,5,3,5,2,6,7,2,4,6,8)

threshold <- 4
```

Is there a way to sum up the differences of all smaller elements of `my_vec` compared to the threshold value?

So the expected result on this example should be 8 (2+1+0+1+0+2+0+0+2+0+0+0)
For my purpose, the sum (8) is all I need (I don't need the difference between every element). I tried this by using a loop but unfortunately, there are several vectors of different length so I can't loop from 1:12 (as on the above vector) on a vector which has only 10 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First subset elements below `threshold` and then sum difference to `threshold`:

```
threshold <- 4
sum((threshold - my_vec[my_vec < threshold]))

# [1] 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pmin` between `my_vec` and  `threshold` to get minimum of them and get `sum` of it's differences with `threshold`.

```
sum(threshold - pmin(my_vec, threshold))
#[1] 8
```